# Does it make sense to analyse the boolean result of an variable assignment?

Tags: c++, c, assign, boolean-operations

I was reading a code just now and I found a very strange code line written by another programmer:

```
if ((socket_obj->client_fd = accept(socket_obj->server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&socket_obj->client_address, &fromlen)) < 0)
```

If I understood correctly, the line is calling the `socket.h` function `accept` which returns an integer value. Once the function is finished, this value is assigned to `socket_obj->client_fd` and then, *the assignment operation* is evaluated if it is lower then 0.

But wouldn't it be always higher then 0 since the boolean result of an value assignment is always true? I mean, won't the following line always return true?

```
if (myVariable = 0)
```

I first thought this was a coding mistaken and changed the code so the assignment first occurs and later the value inside `socket_obj->client_fd` is evaluated against 0, but then I found another place in the code where the same situation occurs, so I can't assume it's an isolated mistake.

I'ld like to know, then, if my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Nope.  You should go read up on the assignment operator.  Or try your example and see what happens.

Comment: BTW did you mean `if (myVariable == 0)` instead of `if (myVariable = 0)` ? `(myVariable = 0)` is always false.

Comment: @MichaelWalz no, I'm talking about evaluating an assignment operator, not a comparison. So it's exactly as I wrote. (and wouldn't it return always `true` instead of `false` as you sad? At least this is what I remember a compiler once saying)

Comment: @Momergil `if (myVariable = 0)` puts 0 into `myVariable` and the conditional statement that comes after will never be executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An assignment does not return `true`. Try it out for yourself. An assignment returns the value that has been assigned.

```
int main() {
    int a;
    std::cout << ( (a = 0) ? "true" : "false" ) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the resulting value does not need to be `true` or `false`. For example, that's why you can do:

```
int x, y;
x = y = 4; // both x and y are 4 now
```

This is equivalent to:

```
x = ( y = 4 );
```

And since `y`'s assignment returns the value assigned to `y`, which is `4`, `x` also gets it.

Comment: @haccks What? The question is `I mean, won't the following line always return true?`. Read again.

Comment: @haccks coffee time ;)

Comment: Ternary operator is not required to explain this, I think example without it would be easier to understand.

Comment: @Svalorzen Running your code I noticed the truth. Thanks for the answer! (now I'm wondering myself why didn't I test that easy code by myself before coming to SO...)

Answer (score 5):

In C and C++ the built-in assignment operator returns its left operand after assignment. So the line

```
if ((socket_obj->client_fd = accept(...)) < 0)
```

does the following:

1. Calls `accept()`
2. Assigns its result to `socket_obj->client_fd`.
3. Compares `socket_obj->client_fd` with `0`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Savin! I now understand where my mistake was.